# red light before backslash in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

when I write the directory of the file, Sublime Text shows this annoying red light before some backslashes. How can I get this to go away?

note: The code runs without any errors.
[image: ST python screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text highlights raw strings starting with a lowercase `r` as Regular Expressions, which is why `\c` and `\M` are highlighted as an illegal escape character in regex. You'll also notice the different highlighting on `\U`, `\h` and `\D` in your screenshot.

To prevent Sublime Text from treating your raw string as a regular expression, simply use an uppercase `R` for the raw string, like:
[image: ST highlighting python code with raw strings and Windows paths]

Answer (score 1):

Replace backslash "\" instead of forelash "/"

or

use double backslashes "\\"

In Python, backslash means escape sext character.

Comment: i used // and the red light gone, thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: `Preferences > Customize Color Scheme`
2. Copy-paste from `Custom theme rules` to `User rules` "Invalid" rule
3. Change `Invalid background` rule (copy from background rule from current scheme)
4. Change `Invalid foreground` rule (copy from foreground "String" rule from current scheme)
5. Save

[image]

Done

[image]